# How to pull a field from MS ACCESS in the VBA Code in the same DB

Tags: database, vba, ms-access, outlook

I Have a Database in MS ACCESS in which i have a ECount field which holds some Counts
is there any way i can pull that call in VBA code where i am generating a new mail which should pull the count in the mail.

```
Private Sub Command_Click()
Dim objOutlook As Outlook.Application
Dim objEmail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim ThisDay As Date

ThisDay = Format(Now, "mm/dd/yy")


Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.application")
Set objEmail = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

With objEmail
    .To = ""
    .CC = ""
    .Subject = "Daily Email Processed " *(Thisday)
    .Body = "Hi," + vbNewLine + vbNewLine + vbNewLine + "Please find below the number of Emails processed for the  " + vbNewLine + vbNewLine + "Email Count = " (**ECOUNT**) + vbNewLine + "O Count = " (**OCount**)
    .Attachments.Add ""
    .Attachments.Add ""
    .Display
    '.ReadReceiptRequested

End With
```

Comment: Where is the ECount field? In a table/query?

Comment: sorry about that its in a query...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs1 As DAO.Recordset
Dim sCount As String

Set db = CurrentDb()
Set rs1 = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT TOP 1 ECounter FROM [Email Query]")

If rs1.RecordCount > 0 Then
    rs1.MoveFirst
    sCount = rs1.Fields("ECount")
End If
rs1.Close
set rs1 = Nothing
set db = Nothing
```

`sCount` will hold the value

Comment: Giving error like too few parameters for Set rs1 = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT TOP 1 ECount FROM YourQuery") @ Andrey Gordeev

Comment: @user1897472 well, replace `ECount` by field name you want to get

Comment: I did it the first time and the query name as well and got the error Set rs1 = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT TOP 1 ECounter FROM Email Query") is what I Have

Comment: @user1897472 `Email Query` is the name of your query?

Comment: @user1897472 You got a good example why you shouldn't use whitespaces in field/table/query/report names. Try this: `Set rs1 = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT TOP 1 ECounter FROM [Email Query]")`

Comment: You know what that was brilliant Mate . Really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to retrieve a singular field from a table/query is to use the `DLOOKUP` function of Access.

So you could write:

```
    .Body = "Hi," + vbNewLine + vbNewLine + vbNewLine + _
        "Please find below the number of Emails processed for the  " + vbNewLine + vbNewLine + _
        "Email Count = " + DLookup("ECount", "SourceTableOrQuery", "Criteria1 = 5 and Criteria2 = ""Test""") + vbNewLine + _
        "O Count = " +  DLookup("OCount", "SourceTableOrQuery")
```

Alternatively, if you don't have the count yet, but want to count the number of items, you can use the 'DCount` function.

Comment: I am Getting an Error here --- .Body = "Hi," + vbNewLine + vbNewLine + vbNewLine + "Emails processed for the  " & ThisDay + vbNewLine + vbNewLine + "Email Count        =  " + DLookup("Ecounter", "Email Query") + vbNewLine + "Outbound Count = " + DLookup("Ecounter", "Email Query")

Comment: What happens when you execute `? DLookup("Ecounter", "Email Query")` in the Immediate window? Is Email Query really the name of your query and Ecounter the name of the field? Does the query only return one row?

Comment: Run time error 13 Type mismatch and yes that is the name for the query and Ecounter is an Expression which stored by the query in the query..

Comment: Hard to debug from remote, but DLookup is pretty simple - play around with it a bit and you'll hopefully get the right syntax. See some examples here: http://access.mvps.org/access/general/gen0018.htm

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs1 As DAO.Recordset
Dim sCount As String

Set db = CurrentDb()
Set rs1 = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT TOP 1 ECounter FROM [Email Query]")

If rs1.RecordCount > 0 Then
    rs1.MoveFirst
    sCount = rs1.Fields("ECount")
End If
rs1.Close
set rs1 = Nothing
set db = Nothing
```